# Looking for hechshered plain kefir Kosher for Passover

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, passover

Does anyone know of hechshered plain kefir gluten free no additives Kosher for Passover?

Kefir is a fermented milk product (cow, goat or sheep milk) that tastes like a drinkable yogurt.

> Kefir contains high levels of vitamin B12, calcium, magnesium, vitamin K2, biotin, folate, enzymes, and probiotics.

—See The Well, http://shopthewell.co/2015/02/02/benefits-kefir/

Answer (score 0):

Based on my deduction from information I found on [this OU page](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-news/easy-to-eat-complex-to-certify-yogurt-is-a-favorite-food-for-the-cultured-among-us/):

> Kefir is a yogurt-type beverage made by fermenting milk with kefir
>   grains. These grains consist of **yeast** and bacteria, in an environment
>   of sugars, proteins and lipids.

Yeast **might** be considered chametz depending on whether it grew off of barley or wheat or one of the other 3 "chametz" grains. This is common in the industry. (See this [M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15683/5275) for more info. )

I haven't seen any Pesach kefir around. I'm assuming that within the industry, there is no non-chametz form of yeast that's around or that is cheap enough to produce. This could also be that there is not enough of a demand for kefir on Pesach that companies want to make a special Pesach "blend".

Comment: Where do you see a difference if the yeast was derived from barley and wheat or the other three?